# SPN command for saving files in share location

Tags: windows, iis

I am using windows authencation  and asp.net impersation is enabled.
I have deployed my application on server "ABC" everything works fine except file save.Files need to be saved on server: "XYZ".I am able to browse/Open the shared location from "ABC" Server

The code works fine from my development machine to shared location. Only on the server, it fails to save files on share location
Some suggest it is an issue due to SPN double hop problem 
How to register an SPN for a folder of the different server?
I do not want to change my app pool Application Pool Identity to Custom account(This is very tough most of my application will fil in this setting)

In My server "Abc" I am trying to register the command

Setspn -S \muse-s-10180.abc.EY.com\Sharefolder\Images\

but this command is failing

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a straight forward answer because SPN is a combination of both hostname and the account under which application pool is running.

Could you please share how you save the file on remote server? i.e over http protocol or using \

Here is what you need to do.

1. Check if the application pool is running under a custom domain account or in-built machine account.
2. Click on the website in IIS. Open Configuration editor and navigate to system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication and check if "useAppPoolCredentials" is set to true or false.
3. Run the following command setspn -f -q */hostname and share the results. For Example, if the URL of the application is http://test.com/sample/windows/authentication, your command will be setspn -f -q */test.com
4. Open Active Directory users and Computers, navigate to the machine name where IIS is installed ( do not do a find), right click and go to delegate. Ensure delegation is enabled.

I can share the next steps based on the results that you share.

Comment: My share path is like this  \\muse-s-10180.abc.EY.com\Sharefolder\Images\

Comment: Yes did the above steps as specified and delegation is enabled

Comment: Ok great ! What error do you get when you try to save the file ? Does it prompt for credentials ?